# Why does knnImpute preProcess change other data? Is this in error

Tags: r, missing-data, r-caret, knn

Here's some data:

```
> head(p.full)[,1:3]
     id timestamp full_sq
1 30474     16617   39.00
2 30475     16617   79.20
3 30476     16617   40.50
4 30477     16617   62.80
5 30478     16617   40.00
6 30479     16617   48.43
```

There are some missing values not shown above so I used preProcess from caret to fill them with median values:

```
p.full.medians <- predict(preProcess(p.full, method=c("medianImpute")), p.full)

> head(p.full.medians)[,1:3]
     id timestamp full_sq
1 30474     16617   39.00
2 30475     16617   79.20
3 30476     16617   40.50
4 30477     16617   62.80
5 30478     16617   40.00
6 30479     16617   48.43
```

Exact same as above, expected since the same df I showed had no missing values.

But then I tried with knn impute:

```
p.full.knn <- predict(preProcess(p.full, method=c("knnImpute")), p.full)
> head(p.full.knn)[,1:3]
        id timestamp    full_sq
1 1.036042 0.9665495 -0.4296467
2 1.036133 0.9665495  0.7133352
3 1.036224 0.9665495 -0.3869981
4 1.036315 0.9665495  0.2470441
5 1.036405 0.9665495 -0.4012143
6 1.036496 0.9665495 -0.1615293
```

Now values throughout the dataframe have been changed whereas I expected only NA values to be changed.

Is this expected? Have I misunderstood how knnImpute works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected and mentioned in the documentation. When using `knnImpute` data is scaled and centered by default (this is why you see values around zero).

From the [documentation](http://topepo.github.io/caret/pre-processing.html#impute):

> preProcess  can be used to impute data sets based only on information in the training set. One method of doing this is with K-nearest neighbors. For an arbitrary sample, the K closest neighbors are found in the training set and the value for the predictor is imputed using these values (e.g. using the mean). Using this approach will automatically trigger  preProcess  to center and scale the data, regardless of what is in the  method  argument.

Comment: Ah, it's scaled. Of course, I should have noticed that. Thank you very much!